# Get user location for bot framework

Tags: botframework

I am developing a bot using botframework in C# and I'll be using the web connector.

How can I get hold of my user location "gps coordinate" when needed?

Comment: Aye, that entirely depends on the actual hardware environment in which the application, and/or the user, is running.  (It *also* depends on whether-or-not said User is **foolish** enough to share their location with you!  More and more people now understand the risks inherent in doing so.)

Answer (score 0):

Only some of the channels allow users to share their location (i.e. Telegram).  In those cases, the bot needs to ask the user to share their location and then the user needs to take explicit action within the channel to share the location.  When they do, this data will be sent back to the bot.

Comment: For those clients that don’t allow users to share location you might consider explicitly asking a user for their location and use the new location control: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location